# why is the input of a bootstrap inline form wider with validation format

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

When I use the validation elements in an inline form with Bootstrap 3, the input's width is getting wider.

From my observation the normal case is that when the input element is verified 30.5px are removed from the input width and its padding is increased by 30.5px to give space for the glyphicon span. But in the inline form although the padding is increased, the width of the input is not decreased.

Here's the validation elements I am using :

```
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <label class="sr-only " for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
```

And here's a plunker to illustrate the comparison between two forms (you need to use full screen): [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MaNscQLTGBIOLTL3n5xy?p=preview)

I'm not sure if this is a bootstrap bug or if I'm missing a class in my html.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess they did this on purpose. So the text input space has still the same size and doesn't get shrink down with validation. If you use this validation feature, it's most likely that you do so in every input and as a result every input will have the same width again.. If you don't want to use the validation icon on every input, you could still give every `.form-group`the `.has-feedback`class, but don't include the `span`. But it's just a guess..

Comment: Hi @Sebsemillia, this would not be consistent with the behaviour of form-horizontal where the total size of the form-group stays the same and width is transferred from the input to its padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that this is indeed intended behaviour for the form-inline class. I don't really understand why this class behaves like this when the form-horizontal class behaves differently, but ok! 
So here's the workaround I got from the github issue I have posted.

You just need to add the following css:

```
.form-inline .has-feedback .form-control {
  padding-right: 12px;
}
```